# AJAX / PHP echo flashes correct text then erases it

Tags: javascript, ajax

OK, this is weird. The following code is intended to be an introductory exercise for me to start out with AJAX where I enter some text into a text input, click a submit button, and have AJAX / PHP echo this back as text within a div. When I step through this code one line at a time, I can see my text appear in my div right on the line where it is supposed to. But then, when I step across the very last curly bracket, the text disappears! How can this be?? I don't get it. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!-- 
        window.onload = function ajaxFunction() {
            document.myform.onsubmit = getFeedback;
        }

        function getFeedback() {
            var textvalue = document.getElementById("textfield").value;
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {  
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML=textvalue;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","scripts/handle_feedback.php?mytext="+textvalue,true);
            //at this point in the execution, my text is displayed correctly...
            xmlhttp.send();
        } //...but when I step across this line, the text disappears!!!
    //-->
    </script>

    <div id="textboxdiv">
        <form name="myform">
            Text Here: <input type="text" id="textfield" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="feedback">
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're not cancelling the default form action of submitting the entire page.

Since there's no `action` attribute on the form, the default action is to submit to the current URL - which effectively just reloads the current page.

You're handling the form yourself via javascript and ajax, so you don't need the default action, and need to cancel it.

There's two ways to fix this:

1. Return `false` from the `getFeedback()` function

   or...
2. Don't use a `submit` button in the first place. If you change your button to `type="button"`, there's no default action to worry about. Without the javascript, clicking that type of a button does nothing, so you don't need to worry about cancelling a submit.

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much. I've spent an hour trying to figure this out. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

`getfeedback()` needs to end with:

```
return false;
```

to prevent the default form submission from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Add: `return false` to the  end of your getFeedback function

Another possible solution would be to use jquery.

With jquery you could simply use

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()  //stops the form actually submitting
    $('#feedback').load('scripts/handle_feedback.php?mytext='+$("#textfield").val());
});
```

Also you'd need to give the button an ID

```
<button type="submit" id="mybutton">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Really? This has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery, and jQuery is absolutely not necessary. I would **not** recommend starting to learn javascript and ajax by using jQuery. jQuery can be useful, but it's always helpful to know the underlying language/technology first.

Comment: I agree it's important to learn the underlying script first. I'm simply showing how this can be done with jquery in just a few simple lines of code. Judging be the poster's other questions they already seem to have a good handle on javascript and I think it could have been something previously overlooked and useful to the poster or other people looking into ajax.

Comment: I'll accept that enough to remove my -1, but I won't go so far as to upvote it.

Comment: Thanks, I've amended my answer to be less pro-jquery and more as an informative alternative.